# Tensorflow frozen graph protobuf does not predict using c api

Tags: python, c, tensorflow, keras

I have trained model for semantic segmentation using [this repo](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models), got good results and tried to use this net in small library writen with tensorflow c API. I turned my keras model into protobuf file using [this repo](https://github.com/amir-abdi/keras_to_tensorflow) and run session using this code:

```c
typedef struct model_t {
    TF_Graph* graph;
    TF_Session* session;
    TF_Status* status;

    TF_Output input, target, output;

    TF_Operation *init_op, *train_op, *save_op, *restore_op;
    TF_Output checkpoint_file;
} model_t;

typedef struct NetProperties {
    int width;
    int height;
    int border;
    int classes;
    int inputSize;
} NetProperties;

static model_t * model;
static NetProperties * properties;

extern "C" EXPORT int ModelCreate(const char* nnFilename, const char* inputName, const char* outputName, int pictureWidth, int pictureHeight, int border, int classes) {
    ModelDestroy();
    model = (model_t*)malloc(sizeof(model_t));;
    model->status = TF_NewStatus();
    model->graph = TF_NewGraph();
    properties = (NetProperties*)malloc(sizeof(NetProperties));
    properties->width = pictureWidth;
    properties->height = pictureHeight;
    properties->border = border;
    properties->classes = classes;
    properties->inputSize = (pictureWidth + border * 2) * (pictureHeight + border * 2) * 3;
    {
        // Create the session.
        TF_SessionOptions* opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
        model->session = TF_NewSession(model->graph, opts, model->status);
        TF_DeleteSessionOptions(opts);
        if (!Okay(model->status)) return 0;
    }

    TF_Graph* g = model->graph;

    {
        // Import the graph.
        TF_Buffer* graph_def = read_file(nnFilename);
        if (graph_def == NULL) return 0;
        printf("Read GraphDef of %zu bytes\n", graph_def->length);
        TF_ImportGraphDefOptions* opts = TF_NewImportGraphDefOptions();
        TF_GraphImportGraphDef(g, graph_def, opts, model->status);
        TF_DeleteImportGraphDefOptions(opts);
        TF_DeleteBuffer(graph_def);
        if (!Okay(model->status)) return 0;
    }

    // Handles to the interesting operations in the graph.
    model->input.oper = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, inputName);
    model->input.index = 0;
    model->target.oper = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "target");
    model->target.index = 0;
    model->output.oper = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, outputName);
    model->output.index = 0;


    model->init_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "init");
    model->train_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "train");
    model->save_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "save/control_dependency");
    model->restore_op = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "save/restore_all");

    model->checkpoint_file.oper = TF_GraphOperationByName(g, "save/Const");
    model->checkpoint_file.index = 0;
    // first prediction is slow
    unsigned char * randomData = (unsigned char*)malloc(properties->inputSize * sizeof(unsigned char));
    for (int i = 0; i < properties->inputSize; i++) {
        randomData[i] = (unsigned char)100;
    }
    ModelPredict(randomData);
    free(randomData);
    return 1;
}

extern "C" EXPORT void ModelDestroy() {
    if (model == nullptr) return;
    TF_DeleteSession(model->session, model->status);
    Okay(model->status);
    TF_DeleteGraph(model->graph);
    TF_DeleteStatus(model->status);
    free(model);
}

extern "C" EXPORT unsigned char* ModelPredict(unsigned char * batch1) {
    if (model == NULL) return NULL;

    const int64_t dims[4] = { 1, properties->height + properties->border * 2, properties->width + properties->border * 2, 3 };
    size_t nbytes = properties->inputSize;

    // can be faster
    float * arrayOfFloats = (float*)malloc(nbytes * sizeof(float));
    //float sumUp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < properties->inputSize; i++) {
        arrayOfFloats[i] = batch1[i] * (1.f / 255.f);
        //sumUp += arrayOfFloats[i];
    }
    //std::cout << sumUp << std::endl;
    // removed due to jdehesa answer
    //float ** inputFloats = (float**)malloc(nbytes * sizeof(float*));
    //inputFloats[0] = arrayOfFloats;


    // Optionally, you can check that your input_op and input tensors are correct
    //// by using some of the functions provided by the C API.
    //std::cout << "Input op info: " << TF_OperationNumOutputs(input_op) << "\n";
    //std::cout << "Input data info: " << TF_Dim(input, 0) << "\n";

    std::vector<TF_Output> inputs;
    std::vector<TF_Tensor*> input_values;
    TF_Operation* input_op = model->input.oper;
    TF_Output input_opout = { input_op, 0 };
    inputs.push_back(input_opout);
    // reworked due to jdehesa answer
    //TF_Tensor* input = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT, dims, 4, (void*)inputFloats, //nbytes * sizeof(float), &Deallocator, NULL);
    TF_Tensor* input = TF_NewTensor(TF_FLOAT, dims, 4, (void*)arrayOfFloats, nbytes * sizeof(float), &Deallocator, NULL);
    input_values.push_back(input);

    int outputSize = properties->width * properties->height * properties->classes;

    int64_t out_dims[] = { 1, properties->height, properties->width, properties->classes };

    // Create vector to store graph output operations
    std::vector<TF_Output> outputs;
    TF_Operation* output_op = model->output.oper;
    TF_Output output_opout = { output_op, 0 };
    outputs.push_back(output_opout);

    // Create TF_Tensor* vector
    //std::vector<TF_Tensor*> output_values(outputs.size(), nullptr);

    // Similar to creating the input tensor, however here we don't yet have the
    // output values, so we use TF_AllocateTensor()
    TF_Tensor* output_value = TF_AllocateTensor(TF_FLOAT, out_dims, 4, outputSize * sizeof(float));
    //output_values.push_back(output_value);

    //// As with inputs, check the values for the output operation and output tensor
    //std::cout << "Output: " << TF_OperationName(output_op) << "\n";
    //std::cout << "Output info: " << TF_Dim(output_value, 0) << "\n";

    TF_SessionRun(model->session, NULL,
        &inputs[0], &input_values[0], inputs.size(),
        &outputs[0], &output_value, outputs.size(),
        /* No target operations to run */
        NULL, 0, NULL, model->status);
    if (!Okay(model->status)) return NULL;

    TF_DeleteTensor(input_values[0]);

    // memory allocations take place here
    float* prediction = (float*)TF_TensorData(output_value);
    //float* prediction = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * properties->inputSize / 3 * properties->classes);
    //memcpy(prediction, TF_TensorData(output_value), sizeof(float) * properties->inputSize / 3 * properties->classes);
    unsigned char * charPrediction = new unsigned char[outputSize * sizeof(unsigned char)];
    sumUp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < outputSize; i++) {
        charPrediction[i] = (unsigned char)((prediction[i] * 255));
        //sumUp += prediction[i];
    }
    //std::cout << sumUp << std::endl << std::endl;
    //free(prediction);
    TF_DeleteTensor(output_value);
    return charPrediction;
}
```

The problem is that prediction result is always the same. I tried to pass random data and real images but the result was equal. However, defferent trained models give different prediction result, but for each model it's always same. As you can see in code snippet, I checked that pass different data and get same prediction every time

```
// first is float sum of passed picture, second is the float sum of answer
724306
22982.6

692004
22982.6

718490
22982.6

692004
22982.6

720861
22982.6

692004
22982.6
```

I tried to write my own keras to tensorflow .pb converter but result was the same.

```py
import os, argparse

import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.keras.utils import get_custom_objects
from segmentation_models.losses import bce_dice_loss,dice_loss,cce_dice_loss
from segmentation_models.metrics import iou_score

# some custom functions from segmentation_models
get_custom_objects().update({
      'dice_loss': dice_loss,
      'bce_dice_loss': bce_dice_loss,
      'cce_dice_loss': cce_dice_loss,
      'iou_score': iou_score,
    })

def freeze_keras(model_name):
    tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_name)
    sess = tf.keras.backend.get_session()
    constant_graph = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), [out.op.name for out in model.outputs])
    tf.train.write_graph(constant_graph, './', 'saved_model.pb', as_text=False)

freeze_keras('best-weights.hdf5')
```

Help me to find out how to fix prediction result in c api.

UPDATE 1: Reworked input array as jdehesa suggested

UPDATE 2: Added definition of `model` and `NetProperties`

Comment: What is the output of your model? If you are classifying each pixel in the image, and the output is something like softmax, shouldn't then the total sum always be the same? (since for each pixel you have `classes` values that add up to 1). The resulting sum in that case should be an integer though (I mean a float ending in `.0` or close), concretely the total number of pixels in the image, and `.6` seems too much and too consistent for a precision errors in the sum.

Comment: @jdehesa my model output is one class (512x512x1 to be precise). I used openCV to show images and predictions before and noticed the pattern of prediction was the same despite different input images, so I tried to prove my theory that prediction is always the same and sum up all pixels output, now I'm in doubt is this method good as proof. Activation function in output is sigmoid. I have good results doing the same with python and answers are different.

Comment: Post definition and declaration of `model`.

Comment: @chux Added to the beggining of code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the model. I have trained it using not normalized data from images (pixel values are between 0.0 and 255.0) and tried to interfere normilezed data (I devided each pixel value by 255 `arrayOfFloats[i] = batch1[i] * (1.f / 255.f);` and got values between 0.0 and 1.0) so my model thought that it gets black images every time and gave me similar answers. So I removed normalization and the model started to predict.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not setting the input data correctly. Let's see.

```
float * arrayOfFloats1 = (float*)malloc(nbytes * sizeof(float));
float sumUp = 0;
```

Here you create `arrayOfFloats1` to hold all the image data.

```
for (int i = 0; i < properties->inputSize; i++) {
    arrayOfFloats1[i] = batch1[i] * (1.f / 255.f);
    sumUp += arrayOfFloats1[i];
}
std::cout << sumUp << std::endl;
```

Here you set `arrayOfFloats1` to the image data. This is all fine.

But then:

```
float ** inputFloats = (float**)malloc(nbytes * sizeof(float*));
```

Here you have `inputFloats`, which has space for `nbytes` float pointers. First, you probably would want to allocate space for float values, not float pointers (which probably do not have the same size). And then:

```
inputFloats[0] = arrayOfFloats1;
```

Here you are setting the first of those `nbytes` pointers to the pointer `arrayOfFloats1`. And then `inputFloats` is used as input to the model. But the remaining `nbytes - 1` pointers have not been set to anything. Although not required, they are probably set all to zero.

If you just want to make an "array of arrays of floats" with `arrayOfFloats1` you don't need to allocate any memory, you can simply do:

```
float ** inputFloats = &arrayOfFloats1;
```

But then you actually use `inputFloats` like this:

```
TF_Tensor* input = TF_NewTensor(
    TF_FLOAT, dims, 4, (void*)inputFloats, nbytes * sizeof(float), &Deallocator, NULL);
```

So here you are saying that `input` is made up of the data in `inputFloats`, which will be a pointer to `arrayOfFloats1` and then uninitialized memory. Probably you actually want something like:

```
TF_Tensor* input = TF_NewTensor(
    TF_FLOAT, dims, 4, (void*)arrayOfFloats1, nbytes * sizeof(float), &Deallocator, NULL);
```

Which means `input` will be a tensor made up of the data in `arrayOfFloats1` that you copied before. In fact, I don't think your code needs `inputFloats` at all.

Otherwise, from what I can tell the rest of the code seems correct. You should ensure that all allocated memory is properly freed in all cases (e.g. when you do `if (!Okay(model->status)) return NULL;` you should probably delete the input and output tensors before returning), but that is a different issue.

Comment: Thanks, now I see this strange code. I removed `inputFloats` but still get pattern-like answer. I'm going to triple check incoming values that I make float.

Comment: @VladislavD In your edited code now you pass `arrayOfFloats` to `TF_NewTensor` instead of `arrayOfFloats1`, is that just a typo or is `arrayOfFloats` something else?

Comment: Oh, it's typo, my bad, renamed `arrayOfFloats1` to `arrayOfFloats` in code

Comment: I checked input values - my model was trained using rgb pictures but in C API I load them with openCV and give model Mat data pointer to bgr pictures flipped horizontally. I fixed that but have no improvement in prediction, it's still one answer for all input. Rechecked model prediction in python - all good, converted model to .pb, load with C API - same wrong answer. Checked answer manually before any conversations - output tensor data contains wrong answer that I display with openCV. Any idea what else can I check for errors?

Comment: @VladislavD Mmh, strange, have you tried loading the serialized `.pb` file into a new graph Python and doing the prediction there? (like `with open(pb_file, 'rb') as f: { gd = tf.GraphDef(); gd.MergeFromString(f.read()); ... = tf.import_graph_def(gd, return_elements=...); }`) Just to make sure the serialized file is correct.

Comment: I solved the problem... I trained model with not normalized data (pixels data were represented as [0.0, 255.0]) and tried to feed normalized([0.0, 1.0]) images to C API model. Thats why I constantly get same answer - normilized data has too small difference despite original values and look like totally black pictures for model. Anyway, great thanks for response! Should I post this as answer or just modify my question?

Comment: @VladislavD Glad you found and solved the problem. Feel free to post and accept your own answer.